# Why does MAX statement require a Group By?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I understand why the first query needs a `GROUP BY`, as it doesn't know which date to apply the sum to, but I don't understand why this is the case with the second query. The value that ultimately is the max amount is already contained in the table - it is not calculated like `SUM` is.   thank you

```sql
-- First Query
select
    sum(OrderSales),OrderDates
From Orders


-- Second Query
select
    max(FilmOscarWins),FilmName
From tblFilm
```

Comment: Tip: SSMS isn't the database, it's just a program for talking to it. The actual database is Microsoft SQL Server, so that's the tag you need to use to ask questions about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not the `SUM` and `MAX` that require the `GROUP BY`, it is the *unaggregated* column.

If you just write this, you will get a single row, for the maximum value of the `FilmOscarWins` column across the whole table:

```
        select
            max(FilmOscarWins)
        From
            tblFilm
```

If the most Oscars any film won was 12, that one row will say 12. But there could be multiple films, all of which won 12 Oscars, so if we ask for the `FilmName` alongside that 12, there is no single answer.

By adding the `Group By`, we fundamentally change the query: instead of returning one number *for the whole table*, it will return one row *for each group* - which in this case, means one row for each film.

If you do want to get a list of all those films which had the maximum 12 Oscars, you have to do something more complicated, such as using a sub-query to first find that single number (12) and then find all the rows matching it:

```
select
     FilmOscarWins,
     FilmName
From
     tblFilm
Where FilmOscarWins = (
        select
            max(FilmOscarWins)
        From
            tblFilm
)
```

Comment: Thank you. If there was a single answer, say that there was only 1 record with the max value, would there still be an error because the interpreter (I think this is what SMSS is?) simply will never let such a query exist, even though such a table would be possible to make?

Comment: Yes, the database (SQL Server itself, not SSMS; although SSMS might spot the problem and give you advance warning) would reject the query as *illogical*, before even looking at the data. (An exception to this you might come across is in a different database system, MySQL, which has a mode where it allows the query and effectively picks a row at random; it's generally considered best to switch that mode off.)

Comment: Yes, because the query is parsed and compiled before being executed, it has to be syntactically and functionally correct; SQL Server cannot know what data it is going to find until the query is executed, at which time the execution plan already exists. Further, think about what would happen if SQL Server *did* allow your syntax because it checked the data at compile time - as soon as that data were to change, the execution plan is invalidated and caching no longer makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the film with the most Oscar wins, then use `select top`:

```
select top (1) f.*
From tblFilm f
order by FilmOscarWins desc;
```

In an aggregation query, the `select` columns need to be consistent with the `group by` columns -- the unaggregated columns in the `select` must match the `group by`.